# Converting char to int when asked to enter an integer and checked with isdigit

Tags: c++

So recently, I came across using isdigit as a way to check to see if an entered value for an int is actually an integer, rather than a string or a char.
However, when I wrote a short program to play around with that, the program failed to execute from that point on.

**EDIT:** I also in the program wanted to take the invalid data and convert it to a different data type.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int enterCFN;
    char revisit;
    int review(0);
    cout << "Enter a digit: ";
    cin >> enterCFN;
    bool y = isdigit(enterCFN);
    if (y == false)
    {
        // This is the data conversion section
         revisit = enterCFN;
         revisit = review;
         cout << review << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << enterCFN << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyone who can correct my error and show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the program is running well on my system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enterCFN` is an `int`.  It stores a number.  `isdigit()` checks if a character represents a number.  These are not the same thing: for example 32 is a number but `char(32)` means `' '` (space).

What you want instead is this:

```
if (cin >> enterCFN)
```

That will take the input from the user and check if it is valid all at once.  No need for `isdigit()`.

Comment: `isdigit` takes an `int` as input according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), although I think you are right about using `cin >> enterCFN` for OP's issue.

Comment: I actually clarified the question a bit. It's also converting the invalid data that was supposed to be an int into either a char or a string.

Answer (score 3):

`isdigit()` checks if a given character is one of `0-9`

For validating integer do something like following:

```
std::cout << "Enter a digit: ";
std::cin >> enterCFN ;
while (1)
{   if ( std::cin >> enterCFN )
    {
        // good input
        break ;
    }
    else
    {
         std::cout << "Enter a digit: ";
         // clear stream flags set due to bad input
         std::cin.clear();
        // get rid of the bad input.
       // ignore the rest of the line
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually clarified the question a bit. It's also converting the invalid data that was supposed to be an int into either a char or a string.